# How the centers of a group and its subgroup are related?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. What can I say about the centers of $G$ and $H$. How are they related?

For example, if I know the center of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is $Z\left[GL(n,\mathbb{R})  \right] = \lbrace \lambda I_{n\times n} \vert \lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{0} \rbrace$, then how can I use this result to deduce the center of $SL(n,R)$?

If I take the center $Z$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ then I take all the matrices of $Z\left[GL(n,\mathbb{R})  \right]$ with determinant 1, I get the center of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Same thing for $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ and for $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$ which makes my life much easier but why ? Which property is behind that ?

Comment: For sure, $\;Z(G)\cap H\le Z(H)\;$

Comment: @Timbuc Unfortunately, that is the wrong inclusion for the "hard" part of this. If only this were over $\mathbb{C}$, it would be easy since then we would have $G = Z(G)H$.

Comment: Yes, but $Z(G) \cap H \le Z(H)$ is all you can say in general. The answer to the question is that you cannot directly use knowledge of the centre of ${\rm GL}$ to calculate that of ${\rm SL}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well, unless the field is algebraically closed (it feels like there should then be some base extension argument, but that does not really make sense for groups).

Comment: If I take the center $Z$ of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ then I take all the matrices of $Z\left[GL(n,\mathbb{R})  \right]$ with determinant 1, I get the center of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.


Same thing for $O(n)$ and $SO(n)$ and for $U(n)$ and $SU(n)$ which makes my life much easier but why ? Which property is behind that ?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think the inclusion I wrote is correct **always**, whenever $\;H\le G\;$ are groups.

Comment: @Timbuc Yes, sorry I was not clear. I just meant that for the specific case at hand, the hard part is showing that the center is no larger than that (and in the case of an algebraically closed field, there is a general way to use the stated facts, it just doesn't seem to carry over). The one you quoted is the only relationship that will hold in general.